# Magento or condition show error Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, customer

Customer OR Condition query show an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object.

The Query :

```
$collection = $this->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('userid')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('firstname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('lastname')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('profile_image')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('specialist')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('latitude')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('longitude')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('group_id', Federallawyer_Customer_Helper_Data::LAWYER);
if ($name != '') {
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter(array('firstname','lastname'), array(
        array('like'=>'%titlesearchtext%'),
        array('like'=>'%contentsearchtext%')
    ));
}

return $collection;
```

Comment: try to clear(comment) each attribute one by one and test your collection you may have an attribute which is not in your collection also you are not telling us where $this comes from so it is not so helpful

Comment: i wrote this query in my customer model, that's why i put $this

Answer (score 0):

Remove one attribute by another until it works, then you know which attribute is broken.

Either the name is wrong or the configuration of the attribute.